# Trying to create a Cross Sign using Silverlight Path element

Tags: xaml, silverlight-4.0, shapes

This is what I have written till now, but this does not work. The first line segment is OK, from (0,0) to (20,20) - a diagonal from top left to bottom right. But, the second line segment is not drawn as a diagonal from top right to bottom left.

I think, I don't know the semantics of this element properly.

Please tell me how to correct this ?

```
<Path Stroke="White" StrokeThickness="3">
<Path.Data>
<GeometryGroup>
<LineGeometry StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="20,20" />
<LineGeometry StartPoint="20,0" EndPoint="0,20" />
</GeometryGroup>
</Path.Data>
</Path>
```

This is what it creates:-

[image: Trying to create cross sign]

Comment: It works for me.  What is your path contained in?

Comment: @Phil My path is contained inside a Grid which is inside a Button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your path in a viewbox so it scales to the size of the button.  For example

```
<Grid>
    <Button Height="23">
        <Viewbox>
                <Path Stroke="White" StrokeThickness="3">
                    <Path.Data>
                        <GeometryGroup>
                            <LineGeometry StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="20,20" />
                            <LineGeometry StartPoint="20,0" EndPoint="0,20" />
                        </GeometryGroup>
                    </Path.Data>
                </Path>
        </Viewbox>
    </Button>
</Grid>
```

or

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Button HorizontalContentAlignment="Left">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Viewbox>
                <Path StrokeEndLineCap="Triangle" StrokeStartLineCap="Triangle" 
                      Stroke="White" StrokeThickness="3">
                    <Path.Data>
                        <GeometryGroup>
                            <LineGeometry StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="20,20" />
                            <LineGeometry StartPoint="20,0" EndPoint="0,20" />
                        </GeometryGroup>
                    </Path.Data>
                </Path>
            </Viewbox>

            <TextBlock Margin="5,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="Press me"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Button>
</Grid>
```